# Add JS library to PATH in Dockerfile

Tags: node.js, npm, dockerfile

I want to add NPM's dependency in Dockerfile like that:

```
RUN PATH="/node_modules/@zxc/pdm-node-builds/dist/bin/pdm-node-scripts.js:$PATH"
RUN export PATH

RUN echo $PATH
```

But it does not work, any other idea?

**EDIT:** My issue was I had:

```
RUN PATH="/node_modules/@zxc/pdm-node-builds/dist/bin/pdm-node-scripts.js:$PATH"
```

where should be:

```
RUN PATH="node_modules/@zxc/pdm-node-builds/dist/bin/pdm-node-scripts.js:$PATH"
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the `ENV` instruction to set environment variables in a Dockerfile. You also don't need the `export` statement in this case.

```
ENV PATH="/node_modules/@zxc/pdm-node-builds/dist/bin/pdm-node-scripts.js:$PATH"
RUN echo $PATH
```

EDIT:
If your script is called `pdm-node-scripts.js` and it's located in `/node_modules/@zxc/pdm-node-builds/dist/bin`, then you should be adding the directory i.e. `/node_modules/@relayr/pdm-node-builds/dist/bin` to `PATH`, not the executable itself.

Comment: But still I get "/bin/sh: ./pdm-node-scripts: not found" which means there is no such library in the PATH ;/

Comment: That sounds like a different issue. If this `pdm-node-scripts` executable is in a directory in your `PATH`, then you shouldn't have `./` in front of it to execute it. If it's in your current working directory, then you need the `./` (and you don't need to add it to `PATH`)

Comment: You might be adding the wrong thing to `PATH`. Check the edited answer.

Comment: Yes, I agree. I know it. Fight to work it.